# Why homology is dual to cohomology? Action of dual to Steenrod algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology

This question seems to me quite basic, but I cannot find the answer.

In order to define coaction of dual Steenrod algebra, we take action on cohomology (here all homology and cohomology are taken with coefficients in a field):
$A\otimes H^*X\rightarrow H^*X$
and dualize it, so we get
$(H^*X)^*\rightarrow A^*\otimes (H^*X)^*$.
Here comes the question: how do I know that $(H^*X)^*\approx H_*X$? Answer should be, since we are in category of vector spaces, that "we take a evaluation homomorphism into bi-dual space". However, the evaluation homomorphism is iso iff the input vector space was finite dimensional. So if I have a space such that its homology is of finite type, that is ok. But this coaction is defined for every space. How?

Comment: It is true that over say fields, cohomology is dual to homology, meaning that the canonical map $\hom(H_*,k) \to H^*$ is an isomorphism. But you need finite dimensionality hypothesis to go the other way.

Comment: I know, so this is what I do not understand here.